# How to check if a value exists in a list in smlnj

Tags: smlnj

I'm working on some homework and I need to create a function that checks if a value exists in a list. If it does it will return true, otherwise it returns false. I have an idea of how to do it but I keep getting errors. I think it may be due to my lack of knowledge of syntax and style as this is my first time coding in sml.

I created the function exist and am passing a value and list in as a tuple.

```
fun exist (x, []) =     
if x = hd ([]) then true        
else if x  = tl ([]) then true    
else false;
```

Sorry if this code is laughably incorrect but I get the error message:
" stdIn:2.6 Warning: calling polyEqual
stdIn:3.11 Warning: calling polyEqual
stdIn:1.6-4.11 Warning: match nonexhaustive
          (x,nil) => ...
val exist = fn : ''a list * 'b list -> bool "

and I'm not really sure how to fix this. Any help would be great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your function is pattern-matching on `[]`, so it can only ever match the empty list.
Also, `hd []` and `tl []` are both errors since the empty list has neither head nor tail.

Further, `if some_condition then true else false` is equivalent to `some_condition`.
(And `if some_condition then false else true` is equivalent to `not some_condition`.)
Logical expressions are usually more readable than chains of conditionals.

And you forgot to recurse; you need to use `exist` on the tail of the list if the first element is not what you're looking for.

Either stick to pattern matching:

```
fun exist (_, []) = false
  | exist (x, y::ys) = x = y orelse exist (x, ys)
```

or don't use it:

```
fun exist (x, xs) = not (null xs) andalso (x = hd xs orelse exist (x, tl xs))
```

Pattern matching is often the most readable solution and gives a clear picture of the various cases.

(You seem to have mixed the two forms, treating `[]` as an identifier rather than a type constructor.)